# Calendar Project Almost done in C

Tags: c, printf, scanf

I am working on a calendar project that was due about 4 days ago but I have been working on it even though the score is going to be grossly diminished because I want to try and understand it. So far I have it to the point where a calendar prints out in debug along with the correct number of days in the calendar. The only things I want to fix are that I want to make the first day of each month start off in the correct position so maybe some sort of loop + "    " so that it can loop 4 spaces to the first day of the month or something like that. Also I want it so that when I enter the month, year, and num months the month and year will show the calendar of a month, while nummonths will display the following months. This is a really hard concept for me to understand. Help is Greatly! Appreciated! I have been working on this for WAYYY to long.

```html
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>

int getdaycode(int month, int year);
void printheader(int month, int year);
int getndim(int month, int year);

int main(void) {
    int  day, month, year, nummonths;
    printf("Enter Month, Year, and number of Months: ");
    if (scanf("%d %d %d", &month, &year, &nummonths) != 3
    ||  year < 0 || month < 1 || month > 12) {
        printf("invalid input\n");
        return 1;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < nummonths; i++) {
        printheader(month, year);
        int numdays = getndim(month, year);
        int daycode = getdaycode(month, year);

        printf("%*s", daycode * 4, "");   /* print 4 spaces for each skipped day */
        for (day = 1; day <= numdays; day++) {
            printf("%3d", day);
            daycode = (daycode + 1) % 7;
            if (daycode != 0)
                printf(" ");
            else
                printf("\n");
        }
        if (daycode != 0)
            printf("\n");
        printf("\n");

        month = month + 1;
        if (month > 12) {
            month -= 12;
            year += 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int getdaycode(int month, int year)
{
 int numdays;
 {
  numdays = ((year - 1) * 365 + ((year - 1) / 4) - ((year - 1) / 100) + ((year - 1) / 400)); // how many days including exceptions

  if (((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0)) || (year % 400 == 0))  //check if leapyear
  {
   if (month == 1)       // January 
    numdays = numdays;
   if (month == 2)       // February 
    numdays = numdays + 31;
   if (month == 3)       // March 
    numdays = numdays + 28 + 31 + 1;
   if (month == 4)       // April 
    numdays = numdays + 31 + 28 + 31 + 1;
   if (month == 5)       // May 
    numdays = numdays + 30 + 31 + 28 + 31 + 1;
   if (month == 6)       // June 
    numdays = numdays + 31 + 30 + 31 + 28 + 31 + 1;
   if (month == 7)       // July 
    numdays = numdays + 30 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 28 + 31 + 1;
   if (month == 8)       // August 
    numdays = numdays + 31 + 30 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 28 + 31 + 1;
   if (month == 9)       // September 
    numdays = numdays + 31 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 28 + 31 + 1;
   if (month == 10)       // October      
    numdays = numdays + 30 + 31 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 28 + 31 + 1;
   if (month == 11)       // November
    numdays = numdays + 31 + 30 + 31 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 28 + 31 + 1;
   if (month == 12)       // December
    numdays = numdays + 30 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 28 + 31 + 1;
  }
  else
  {
   if (month == 1)       // January 
    numdays = numdays;
   if (month == 2)       // February 
    numdays = numdays + 31;
   if (month == 3)       // March 
    numdays = numdays + 28 + 31;
   if (month == 4)       // April 
    numdays = numdays + 31 + 28 + 31;
   if (month == 5)       // May 
    numdays = numdays + 30 + 31 + 28 + 31;
   if (month == 6)       // June 
    numdays = numdays + 31 + 30 + 31 + 28 + 31;
   if (month == 7)       // July 
    numdays = numdays + 30 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 28 + 31;
   if (month == 8)       // August 
    numdays = numdays + 31 + 30 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 28 + 31;
   if (month == 9)       // September 
    numdays = numdays + 31 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 28 + 31;
   if (month == 10)       // October      
    numdays = numdays + 30 + 31 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 28 + 31;
   if (month == 11)       // November
    numdays = numdays + 31 + 30 + 31 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 28 + 31;
   if (month == 12)       // December
    numdays = numdays + 30 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 28 + 31;
  }

 }
 int daycode = (numdays + 1) % 7;
 return daycode;
}

void printheader(int month, int year)
 {
   printf("%14d %1d\n", month, year);
   printf("Sun ");
   printf("Mon ");
   printf("Tue ");
   printf("Wed ");
   printf("Thu ");
   printf("Fri ");
   printf("Sat\n");
  }

int getndim(int month, int year)
{
 int numdays;
 if (((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0)) || (year % 400 == 0))  //check if leapyear
 {
  if (month == 1)       // January 
   numdays = 31;
  if (month == 2)       // February 
   numdays = 29;
  if (month == 3)       // March 
   numdays = 31;
  if (month == 4)       // April 
   numdays = 30;
  if (month == 5)       // May 
   numdays = 31;
  if (month == 6)       // June 
   numdays = 30;
  if (month == 7)       // July 
   numdays = 31;
  if (month == 8)       // August 
   numdays = 31;
  if (month == 9)       // September 
   numdays = 30;
  if (month == 10)       // October      
   numdays = 31;
  if (month == 11)       // November
   numdays = 30;
  if (month == 12)       // December
   numdays = 31;
 }
 else
 {
  if (month == 1)       // January 
   numdays = 31;
  if (month == 2)       // February 
   numdays = 28;
  if (month == 3)       // March 
   numdays = 31;
  if (month == 4)       // April 
   numdays = 30;
  if (month == 5)       // May 
   numdays = 31;
  if (month == 6)       // June 
   numdays = 30;
  if (month == 7)       // July 
   numdays = 31;
  if (month == 8)       // August 
   numdays = 31;
  if (month == 9)       // September 
   numdays = 30;
  if (month == 10)       // October      
   numdays = 31;
  if (month == 11)       // November
   numdays = 30;
  if (month == 12)       // December
   numdays = 31;
 }
 return numdays;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hmmm... I guess you're doing well... but: Who said that February is 28 days for the year requested? ... are you not allowed to use [`mktime`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/mktime) or [`strptime`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strptime)? they provide `struct tm`, which has a field `tm_wday` which you could use to calculate the empty spaces at the beginning of a month...

Comment: if (((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0)) || (year % 400 == 0))

Comment: That says if it is a leap year feb is 29 days if not then 28

Comment: I just need a way to multiply my daycode by "    " four spaces

Comment: And I've never heard of those commands so I'm assuming that it would look strange if I used no commands in my code

Comment: You check for leap years, but it doesn't seem `getdaycode` applies them (it uses 28 days for February)... maybe I'm wrong, I'm just reading through.

Comment: The commands are part of the C89 standard.

Comment: I tested it, and when I enter a leap year like 1996 it out  puts 29 days to calendar, non leap year like 1997 etc outputs 28 days to feb

Comment: All I really need help with is I want to know how to loop the code however many time I enter for Nummonths in my scanf

Comment: As well as I want to find out how to space my start day for the months to the correct start day. as every month outputs the correct number of days spaced correctly, problem is that they are all starting on the first sunday of the month

Comment: Yes, you would get the right amount of days, just not the right `daycode`... I think.

Comment: What about a `for` loop or a `while(daycode--) printf(" ");`...?

Comment: Oh I see what you mean, but how do I multiple a printf "    " by my day code?

Comment: Yeah I'm not getting it. =(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has several issues:

- Your calculation for `daycode` is off by one.
- You do not use `daycode`, not `nummonths` in `main()`, resulting in all months appearing to start on a Sunday.

Here is a suggestion:

```
int main(void) {
    int  day, month, year, nummonths;
    printf("Enter Month, Year, and number of Months: ");
    if (scanf("%d %d %d", &month, &year, &nummonths) != 3
    ||  year <= 0 || month < 1 || month > 12) {
        printf("invalid input\n");
        return 1;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < nummonths; i++) {
        printheader(month, year);
        int numdays = getndim(month, year);
        int daycode = getdaycode(month, year);

        printf("%*s", daycode * 4, "");   /* print 4 spaces for each skipped day */
        for (day = 1; day <= numdays; day++) {
            printf("%3d", day);
            daycode = (daycode + 1) % 7;
            if (daycode != 0)
                printf(" ");
            else
                printf("\n");
        }
        if (daycode != 0)
            printf("\n");
        printf("\n");

        month = month + 1;
        if (month > 12) {
            month -= 12;
            year += 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You also need to fix `getdaycode` by changing the formula to compute it from `numdays` at the end of the function:

```
            ...
        }
        int daycode = (numdays + 1) % 7;
        return daycode;
    }
}
```

If you have learned arrays already, your code could be simplified a lot:

```
static int const days[12] = { 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };
static int const leapdays[12] = { 31, 29, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };

int getdaycode(int month, int year) {
    int numdays = 0;
    if (year > 0) {
        // how many days in previous years including exceptions
        numdays = (year - 1) * 365 + (year - 1) / 4 - (year - 1) / 100 + (year - 1) / 400;
    }
    if (month >= 1 && month <= 12) {
        if (month > 2 && (((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0)) || (year % 400 == 0)))
            numdays += 1;  // count february 29
        for (int i = 0; i < month - 1; i++)
            numdays += days[i];
    }
    // need to offset by one so 1/1/1 falls on a Monday.
    // dates before 1753 are computed according to the
    // proleptic Gregorian calendar.
    return (numdays + 1) % 7;
}

int getndim(int month, int year) {
    if (month < 1 || month > 12)
        return 0;
    else
    if ((year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || (year % 400 == 0))
        return leapdays[month - 1];
    else
        return days[month - 1];
}
```

Comment: I don't know if this helps but.. numdays = ((year - 1) * 365 + ((year - 1) / 4) - ((year - 1) / 100) + ((year - 1) / 400)) is supposed to be numdays = ((year - 1) * 365 + ((year - 1) / 4) - ((year - 1) / 100) + ((year - 1) / 400)+day)

Comment: Maybe this is messing up my daycode, because i removed int day from my getdaycode

Comment: Woah it is working really close to what I am aiming for

Comment: I'll post the code above with a picture of the output and what it is Supposed to be.

Comment: @tyooo: I updated the answer to show you what I mean by changing the formula for `daycode`.

Comment: @tyooo: you are off by 2 days, did you fix the formula correctly?

Comment: Yes after applying the fix to the getdaycode function as you mentioned it fixed it

Comment: Everything is working perfectly well, but I have another question this shouldn't be too much to implement and isn't required but I would like to do it just to personally know. Check the commented chunk of code I am adding to my main. I want to change the month day on the header to a name of the month.

Comment: Would that sort of thing work in naming the month values 1-12 as a name? maybe put it in the header function/

Comment: The code should work, just do not print the `\n` if you want the month and year to appear on the same line.  Using an array would produce much shorter code.

Comment: Yeah, I havn't gotten into arrays yet. But I will definitely look into them. They sound very useful

Answer (score 1):

I did something similar recently because I wanted to know the number of Tuesdays in March, April, and May. So I wrote this code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    char *monthNames[] = { "March", "April", "May" };

    printf( "Enter starting day (0-6): " );
    int day;
    if ( scanf( "%d", &day ) != 1 )
        return 1;

    day = -(day % 7);
    for ( int m = 0; m < 3; m++ ) {
        printf( "\n%s\n", monthNames[m] );
        int maxday = (m == 1) ? 30 : 31;

        while ( day < maxday ) {
            for ( int col = 0; col < 7; col++ ) {
                if ( day < 0 )
                    printf( "   " );
                else if ( day < maxday )
                    printf( " %2d", day+1 );
                day++;
            }
            printf( "\n" );
        }

        if ( day > maxday )
            day = day - maxday - 7;
        else
            day = 0;
    }
}
```

The general idea is the variable `day` starts as a number between `-6` and `0`. As long as `day` is negative, the code prints three spaces. When the `day` is between 0 and the number of days in the month, the code prints a number. At the end of the month, the starting value for `day` is computed for the next month, based on where the previous month ended.